What is the best way to use perlin noise when generating biomes using pygame. Additionally how would I generate stuctures in specific areas?
This is my second stack overflow post and I am kind of new to the coding scene. I know how to code in python with classes and some mid level structures. I am a student who is working on their software assessment for year 12 and I have a few questions which I would like some insight from more knowledgable people.
I am currently working on a 2d top down game in pygame for an assessment. I have been working on more of the back part of it currently. I will link the repo for anyone to look at if they are interested. I am about to start terrain generation and I would like to do something with perlin noise as taken some inspiration off minecraft. I also would like to know what the best way around generating stuctures and "loot" in specific biomes. I don't really know how to make 'rules' and would greatly appreciate some guidence in the right direction.
I have been mainly working on the saving and the other boring functions which I wanted to get out of the way. Any tips and tricks would be greatly appreciated if it saves me time and a headache.
Source code: (I have to update the readme after I make some significant updates)
https://github.com/JimbossJxy/AfterLight
I have not had made an attempt so far as I don't want to go down the spiral of getting too focused in one specific direction.

I don't know how helpful this will be but you might want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11968247/20710955

Thank you, Ill check it out. It does look promising, I have briefly glanced over it and it does look like it would help in my case. @tomdartmoor

You have to include the code as text in the question. See What topics can I ask about here?: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

This answer uses the PyPI perlin-noise module  to generate noise in pygame.
